# How can I create a generic version of a method that creates a list

Tags: java, generics

Is it possible to create the below function into a generic function that I can re-use?

I want to pass in a collection, and return a list of a particular property in the object.

So far example I have this:

```
   private List<Integer> getPropertyABCIdsFromSomeObject(List<SomeObject> someObjects) {
        List<Integer> ids = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for(SomeObject so : someObjects) {
            ids.add(so.getPropertyABCId());
        }
        return ids;
    }
```

So this method works only for type SomeObject, and returns a list of PropertyABCId.

Now if I want a list of some other property, I have to replicate this function with very little that changes.

Can generics save the day here?

Comment: um nope, not in my opinion. You will have to write `getPropertyABCId()` for all the classes you want to get the property abc id

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would need an interface, but yes:

```
interface HasProperty<T> {
    T getProperty();
}

public static <T> List<T> getProperties(List<? extends HasProperty<T>> items) {
    List<T> properties = new ArrayList<T>();
    for (HasProperty<T> item : items) {
        properties.add(item.getProperty());
    }
    return properties;
}
```

Comment: so this couldn't span multiple classes then could it? e.g. Class Users and class Project.

Comment: @Blankman yes, if `Users` and `Project` both `implement HasProperty<Integer>` then you could create a `List<HasProperty<Integer>>` and add both `Users` and `Project` instances to it and pass that into the method

Comment: This solution does not allow for different properties.  For instance, you could not use this solution to list the values of two different properties of the same object.  You need a layer of indirection between the looping code and the property accessor.

Comment: @C.Trimble Sure you can do it: Create another interface if you need to handle another property. I hardly think this point deserves a downvote - ie "this answer is not useful", which is what a downvote is for. Just because you don't find this appealing doesn't mean it's not useful

Comment: @Bohemian I did not mean to offend, but in this context, this answer is a distraction.  If you create a second interface, you will also need a second getProperties(...) method.  This question is about reusing blocks of code, when statements nested in the block need to change.

Answer (score 2):

### Template Based Solution

Define a template like this:

```
public class ConvertListTemplate<A, B>
{
  public List<B> convert( List<A> list ) {
    List<B> result = new ArrayList<B>();
    for( A a : list ) {
      result.add(convertElement(a));
    }
    return result;
  }

  public abstract B convertElement(A element);
}
```

Then do this in your code:

```
List<Integer> result = new ConvertListTemplate<SomeObject, Integer>() {
  public Integer convertElement(SomeObject element) {
    return element.getPropertyABCId();
  }
}.convert(source);
```

### Strategy Based Solution

Use a method like this:

```
public <A, B> List<B> getProperties(
        List<A> list,
        GetPropertyStrategy<? super A, ? extends B> strategy
) {
  List<B> result = new ArrayList<B>();
  for( A a : list ) {
    result.add(strategy.getProperty(a));
  }
  return result;
}
```

With an interface for the strategy:

```
public interface GetPropertyStrategy<A, B>
{
  public B getProperty(A toConvert);
}
```

And then call the method like this:

```
List<Integer> result = getProperties(source, new GetPropertyStrategy<SomeObject, Integer>() {
  public Integer getProperty(SomeObject element) {
    return element.getPropertyABCId();
  }
});
```

Comment: +1 For the strategy-based solution, note that `strategy` could be typed as `GetPropertyStrategy<? super A, ? extends B>` to widen what can be passed in.

Comment: This would allow for better reuse of strategies.  Answer updated.

Comment: I am not sure @PaulBellora's `GetPropertyStrategy<? super A, ? extends B>` makes much sense in the interface definition. Maybe he meant the second method parameter? Also, the strategy solution seems to be what is already available as [`Function` in the guava library](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/FunctionalExplained).

Comment: In an inheritance situation, where the strategy was not done inline, widening the types will allow for better strategy reuse.

Comment: You can also find similar interfaces in the Apache Functor library http://commons.apache.org/sandbox/functor .  I am sure that there a ton of these out there, since a strategy is the best way to inject this kind of indirection, when you are not in a functional language.